# Wizard do Primefaces pula o tab sem validar campos

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Criei uma função javascript para validar campos do formulário composto pelo componente `<p:wizard>` do Primefaces. A função é chamada através do evento `onnext=""`do `<p:wizard>`, ou seja, somente quando a pessoa clica em próximo (para ir para a próxima tab). O problema é que a minha função javascript ela não consegue fazer com que o `<p:wizard>` não pule a tab se as condições não forem satisfeitas.

```
function onnext() {
var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
var cpf = document.getElementById('cpf');

if (nome.value === '') {
    alert('Por favor preencha o campo nome');
    nome.focus;
    return false;
} else if (cpf.value === '') {
    alert('Por favor preencha o campo cpf');
    cpf.focus;
    return false;
}
return true;}
```

Creio eu que o problema está nesses return true e false... mas como não sei o que deveria retornar, peço ajuda aqui a vocês.

```
<p:wizard nextLabel="Próximo" onnext="onnext();" flowListener="#{alunoBean.onFlowProcess}">
<p:tab title="Dados Pessoais">
    <p:panel header="Dados Pessoais">
        <p:messages />                              
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Nome Completo: " for="nome" />
            <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{alunoBean.aluno.nome}" />

            <p:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF: "/>
            <p:inputText  id="cpf" value="#{alunoBean.aluno.cpf}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</p:tab>
<p:tab title="Dados Bancários">        
</p:tab>
<p:tab title="Dados Familiares">        
</p:tab>
```

Com esse javascript aí, se você não preencher os campos e clicar em próximo, ele mostra o `alert('');` e já pula pra próxima tab. A partir dai você só consegue voltar, não consegue pular pra próxima!

Comment: Tente assim `onnext="return onnext();"`

Comment: Melhorou um pouco. Agora ele mostra o alert e não pula, mas se você preencher os campos e ir novamente em próximo, ela vai para o próximo, mas a partir deste ele não pula mais (tipo para o terceiro tab).

Comment: Já tentou colocar `required="true"` no inputText? Assim: `<p:inputText id="nome" value="#{alunoBean.aluno.nome}" required="true" />`

Comment: Eu estava usando isso, problema é que não vou usar javascript somente para obrigar preenchimento de campos, vou usar para por exemplo: campo telefone, poder colocar 9 ou 8 dígitos; campo cpf, poder colocar 11 ou 6 dígitos (cpf's mais antigos tem menos de 11 dígitos)... e só com o inputMask do primefaces não dá pra fazer isso, acho.

Comment: @LuanSilva é que você tem que checar qual aba esta antes de validar provavelmente, entende? Ou seja aplicar uma validação por aba

Comment: Entendo sim, só não tenho ideia de como fazer... não tenho muitos conhecimentos de javascript

Comment: Para descobrir a tab atual acrescente o atributo widgetVar no componente wizard, por exemplo:  `<p:wizard id="wizard"                            widgetVar="wizard" nextLabel="Próximo" onnext="onnext();" flowListener="#{alunoBean.onFlowProcess}">` e depois em seu código javascript obtenha o index da tab assim: `PF('wizard').getStepIndex();`